# Difficulties testing memory on HP Proliant DL380 gen8 dual CPU

Tags: memory, hp-proliant

I suspect I can't see the wood for the trees but I am having massive issues trying to test the memory on an HP Proliant DL380 gen8 system and I need help!

When I use an Ubuntu 20.04 install, boot Grub I can select memtest86+ - The problem I have is that it always freezes at the very start of test 7 in the first few seconds of memory testing.  If anyone can definitively advise that this means the memory is bad I'd appreciate the advice - however from this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/2zgkzh/psa_is_your_memtest86_freezing_dont_panic/) post it seems probable to me its an error with Memtest86+ 5.01.  Its been less then an hour, but thus far "memtester 60G" under Ubuntu has not failed which would seem to support the Reddit post.

I try download and burn a USB image for Memtest86 5.31b (and burn it to an iso with pv.  The iso mounts fine on my desktop) - This fails to boot on the Gen8 server **is there any non-obvious trick to booting this**?

I believe I can't use memtest86 as it requires UEFI boot which Gen8 servers don't do.

I have been unable to find a .elf binary for memtest86+ 5.31b - and, of-course, trying to boot the .bin file fails.

Absent being able to get memtest86 / memtest86+ to work, how good a stand-in is running "memtester 60G"  from Ubuntu 20.04 on a system with 64 gigs of memory?

Is there any way to get memtest86+ working properly on my server, or any good alternative solution which does not require a running that I can use to test the systems memory?

Comment: You could install your own EFI bootloader such as rEFInd, but that seems like a lot of trouble for a system that's being decommissioned. Let whoever gets it as surplus worry about it.

Comment: I'm 95% certain I managed to boot memtest86+ v 5.31b this morning - but it failed on startup with an "Unexpected Interrupt - Halting CPU0" message. ( FWIW as per hint I found on https://www.coreboot.org/Memtest86%2B I compiled it on my main system (which was trivial) and then overwrote the memtest86+.elf binary in /boot on target system.  For anyone just after the binary I uploaded it to https://my.host.net.nz/downloads/memtest86plus-531b.elf

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, while memtest86+ (the open source version at memtest86.org, not the commercial variant) seemed to be abandoned for years, it has been recently updated to v6.00 and works with modern hardware (DDR4 etc)

I have successfully used it with several machines over the last couple of weeks and it works well with Intel CPUs( i5/7 and Xeons) from 2015 and later.